# Сохранить картинку от пользователя телеграм боту в определенный каталог

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Не могу понять как сохранить картинку\фото присланную пользователем боту в определенный каталог!

Например:

1. У пользователя появляются две (или больше) инлайн кнопки (назовем их "Котики" и "Песики")
2. Пользователь жмет "Котики" и бот предлагает ему отправить фото "Отправь фото котика"
3. Пользователь отправляет, фото сохраняется в '/root/TelegramBot/cats', если отправляет что-то другое (не фото, а текст или документ), то бот говорит: "Отправь картинку"
4. Если пользователь нажмет "Песики", то фото должно сохраниться в '/root/TelegramBot/dogs'

> ```
> @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
> def start(message):
>     menu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
>     button_cat = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Котики', callback_data='cat')
>     button_dog = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Песики', callback_data='dog')
>     menu.add(button_cat, button_dog)
>     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери кого отправить', reply_markup=menu)
> ```

Не пойму логику, что делать дальше?)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@tb.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def name(message):
    if message.text == 'Котики':
        msg = tb.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отправьте фотографию")
        tb.register_next_step_handler(msg, photo_c)
    elif message.text == 'Собачки':
        msg = tb.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отправьте фотографию")
        tb.register_next_step_handler(msg, photo_d)

@tb.message_handler(content_types=['photo']
def photo_c(message):
    if message.content_type == 'photo':
        file_info = tb.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id)
        downloaded_file = tb.download_file(file_info.file_path)
        src = '/root/TelegramBot/' + file_info.file_path.replace('cats/', '')
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)
    else:
        pass

@tb.message_handler(content_types=['photo']
def photo_d(message):
    if message.content_type == 'photo':
        file_info = tb.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id)
        downloaded_file = tb.download_file(file_info.file_path)
        src = '/root/TelegramBot/' + file_info.file_path.replace('dogs/', '')
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)
    else:
        pass
```

Если не работает, то попробуйте убрать хендлеры

Comment: Спасибо, все работает без хендлеров)))

Comment: @АлександрНосов Если смог Вам помочь, то буду благодарен, если отметите мой ответ как решение Вашей проблемы